# Attempt to fetch logical page (6:948264) in database 7 failed. It belongs to allocation unit 72057596882452480 not to 72057595956822016

Tags: sql-server, database, dbcc

When running the update query an error occurred (mentioned in the subject line) in the MSSQL server. After run `DBCC CHECKDB ('db_name', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS` and `DBCC CHECKTABLE('table_name', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS)` the error was solved. But after a few days, this error is again shown when running the update query.

The SQL server is commercial and has almost billions of data so every time `DBCC` command is not possible to run. There is no current database backup. Now, **how to fix this problem permanently?**

Comment: This is probably an unhappy SQL Server, and it's letting you know that there's some underlying problem (possibly hardware?) that is causing database corruptions.  Commercial, billions of data, no backup???? Yikes!